# Creating a text editor in Qt with QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I want to create a GUI that will allow the user to open a desired `.txt` file by simply pressing the Browse button. The text file should then be loaded into the GUI for further processing at a later stage.

```
void dictionary::on_browseButton_clicked()
{
    QStringList fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Open File"),"/path/to/file/",tr("txt Files (*.txt)"));
    ui->tableWidget->addItems(fileNames);
}
```

The error I get is that ***class 'QTableWidget' has no member name 'addItems'***.

What is ***'QTableWidget'***?

I am very new to working with classes and I was hoping somebody could explain where I went wrong.

Comment: Huh? The question title has seemingly nothing to do with the error message or the code posted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your GUI has a table widget, hence the QTableWidget.
Take a look at the [QTableWidget class documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html); there's no `addItems()` method, which is why you're getting the error.

Whatever code you're working with is expecting an `addItems()` method to add the data to the QTableWidget so you'll have to implement it yourself, and rewrite your code so it doesn't try to call `addItems()` from the QTableWidget. To do so, you'll likely need to use the [QTableWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html) class and the `setItem()` method, like in this example code (taken from the QTableWidget documentation):

```
QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg((row+1)*(column+1)));
tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);
```